# substr on std::string doesn't work correctly due to presence of some characters that are invisible, but look like spaces

Tags: c++, string

I have a `std::string` that contains characters that I am unable to see, like `\xc2`, etc.

I want substring of my string which is not working correctly due to presence of characters like '    ' When I replace it with spaces in '    ', the substring is giving correct answers. Although this problem has been solved, I don't want any other character to mess this up. How do I root out this problem? [I just want to replace all those unnecessary characters with spaces.]

Comment: String doen't care what bytes it contains, \xc2 or space, its all the same. So you are mistaken when you say that substr works with spaces but not with those other characters. Your issue was something else. The worrying part is that you got unexpected characters in your string in the first place. I would concentrate on figuring out how that happened, not trying to fix it after it has happened.

Comment: What encoding do you use? Is it a `UTF-8` or some single byte encoding like `Windows-1250`

Comment: I see \xc2 when some OS routine replaces ASCII quotes with "smart" quotes.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I recommend to use [this side](http://wandbox.org/) for that purpose.

Comment: Why do you think std::string::substr is the source of your problem?  Did you use the debugger to display the string? or display the string in hex?  Did you add a function to cout the string content in hex?  and / or the substr result in hex?

Answer (score 4):

Your text is most likely UTF-8 unicode (this is the most common encoding these days). \xc2 is part of multi-byte encoding of likely "No-Break Space" (c2 a0) character or something similar. std::string and substring operates on bytes and is completely unaware that you have unicode and that certain pairs of bytes shouldn't be split. You will also get incorrect character count, incorrect capitalization and other strange effects.

The proper way to handle this is to use a library that implements unicode correctly. And this means replacing all strings in your program with unicode aware variants.

I know it's a bit of work, but the alternative is that you fix this place today and tomorrow you find another operation somewhere else that does things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert this string to `std::u16string` using `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t>`.

Example:

```
    #include <codecvt>

    //Something...

    std::string hello = "H€llo World"; 
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> convert;
    std::u16string hello_word_u16 = convert.from_bytes(hello); 
    std::string hello_world_u8 = convert.to_bytes(hello_word_u16);
```

Using u16 (char16_t) you don't need to care about double byte encoding characters.